# Charts in dynamic data display

Tags: c#, charts, highcharts, bar-chart, dynamic-data-display

I'm developing in Microsoft visual studio 2010, including reference dynamic data display.
I want to create graphs such as Bar graph (Int horizental axis X int Vertical axis) and Bar Graph2 (DateTime horizental axis X int Vertical axis) and Pie graph.
What I have been found difficult is to create the bar. I need to take the date from a date base "Access".
All example that I read is the date declired in the c# code.
I really hope you understand me its my first time I'm asking here a question so be nice :) . Thank's and have a good day. 
Links to **working** example would accept in bless.

```
<Window x:Class="GraphService.ManagersCharts.BarChartManager"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d3="http://research.microsoft.com/DynamicDataDisplay/1.0"
        Title="Window1"
        WindowState="Normal"
        Height="500"
        Width="800"
        Background="Wheat">

        <Grid >
        <d3:ChartPlotter Name="plotter"
                         Margin="10,10,20,10">
            <d3:ChartPlotter.HorizontalAxis>
                <d3:HorizontalIntegerAxis Name="HorizentalAxis" />
            </d3:ChartPlotter.HorizontalAxis>
            <d3:ChartPlotter.VerticalAxis>
                <d3:VerticalIntegerAxis Name="VerticalAxis" />
            </d3:ChartPlotter.VerticalAxis>

            <d3:Header FontFamily="Arial"
                       Content="Bar Chart" />
            <d3:VerticalAxisTitle FontFamily="Arial"
                                  Content="" />
            <d3:HorizontalAxisTitle FontFamily="Arial"
                                    Content="" />
        </d3:ChartPlotter>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: hope the following link helps u.....http://dotnetawesome.com/mvc/how-to-create-google-column-chart-with-animation-using-mvc4

Comment: u can add ur code what u did then it will become simple to help

Comment: What I did is to create the basic Graph (Int X Int ) but I don't know how to load data into it and create bars. In addition I don't know how to make the horizental axis as DateTime. Im adding the xaml code I didn't think it's really helps thats just the beggining.